# How to keep history of visiting the same view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a view for a book. It shows a book and a list of related books. When a user presses a related book, the app needs to display the same book view but with a different book. The requirement is that when a user hits the back button, he will see the previous book - not a previous view of a different type (e.g. search results).

I hoped to implement this use case with the standard Navigator similar to how you can register a history token in a browser while actually staying on the same page. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I tried to navigate to the same view with a different book ID:

```
Navigator.push(_viewContext,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            return BookView(id: _newBookId);
          },
        ));
```

but this results in multiple copies of BookView with each one of them calling its Build at the same time. This feels like a bug to me - I would expect Navigator to take care of not creating multiple instances of the same view. The dispose() method of BookView is never called in this scenario.

I am considering keeping the "history" of book IDs in book view's state, and managing the logic of "show the previous book or pop the book view" on my own.

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the ids of the books seen by the user in a List and use [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) passing to the view the id of the last book seen. So when the user clicks on the back button instead of popping the page, you return the same page but passing it the id of the previous book.

Comment: That's what I had in mind, and it actually proved to be easier than messing with Navigator.